# MSSQL Transactional Replication different versions

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

we are currently using a 2008R2 publisher/distributor for replication.
The subscribers are versions 2008R2 and 2012.

Next week, we would like to update our servers step by step.

I read in the docs, that the subscriber must be within 2 versions of the publisher.

Does this mean, i could upgrade the publisher/distributor to 2014 and use subscribers with versions 2008R2, 2012 **and 2017 simultaneously**? (we plan to upgrade the subscribers to SQL-server 2017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server 2014 publisher you can have subscribers of SQL Server 2017
SQL Server 2016,SQL Server 2014,SQL Server 2012,SQL Server 2008 R2,SQL Server 2008

So it is possible. 
Matix will give you a sound idea.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-backward-compatibility?view=sql-server-ver15